# SSL Certificate Issuer History for particular domain or website

Tags: ssl, certificate, tls

Is it possible to find out the history of issuers of SSL certificates for a particular website? For example if a website had a cert issued from one company A originally, then the website had a new certificate issued from company B? Would I be able to find out who company A was and the time the Cert was issued from start to end date? In this scenario I don't have access to the server hosting the website. I've tried looking at the certificate info via web browsers, I don't seem to see any such records.

Comment: This information isn’t categorized for a lot of reasons, a certificate is signed by the Root CA, and most individuals with a certificate only use the single certificate for that specific use. When that certificate expires, a new certificate is generated, and the old certificate is retired. What purpose would a database of expired or revoked certificate serve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, **no**. You would have to manually monitor those changes ahead of time. Current certificates don't have any link to previous ones.

---

That said, Sectigo's certificate log collector: https://crt.sh/ does scan most major public certificate authority logs like Digicert's, and snapshots SSL certificates going back up to 10 years, but may not necessarily monitor the websites you need.

Comment: Website doesn’t work

Comment: @Ramhound It's slow and sometimes times out but ultimately works after a few tries.

Comment: crt.sh isn't crawling public websites, instead it is a search of the issuers CT logs (the CAs put on a public log every time they issue a cert)

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thanks so much, this https://crt.sh seems to have worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to search on some [Certificate Transparency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_Transparency) search engine.

The prime example of such a tool is [crt.sh](https://crt.sh/) by Sectigo's Rob Stradling.

The way those work is by using the data from the Certificate Transparency logs that record all certificates issued by publicly trusted certificate authorities.